# How to add UIView on window in app delegate in swift?

Tags: swift

**view object is not getting in addsubview bracket**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool
    {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, animated: true);
            var myView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 100));
            myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            self.window.?.addSubview(myView)


            return true
    }
```

Comment: DO. NOT. DO. THIS. use the `rootViewController` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Try to use so if access through UIViewController

```
let win:UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!
win.addSubview(self)
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need 2 bangs at the end of this?

Comment: @teradyl This statement helps you put a view on all other view, it is equal add on stack top

Answer (score 4):

please, do the implementation for the stack properly, like e.g. this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let mainViewController: MainViewController = MainViewController(nibName: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)
    window!.rootViewController = mainViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, my application is "single view application" and i want to add view on window so that it can be visible in every view. please tell how to do?

Comment: leave the `UIWindow` class's `subviews` alone. find another solution for your application, if that is a single-view app as you said, your view is at perfectly good location in your view controller's `view` as subview. if that is _not_ a single view app, use the proper navigation stack via navigation- or tabbar-controllers.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your code,
for UIApplication Root view controller's viewDidAppear Function 
add below code.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!.bringSubviewToFront((UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!.subviews[0]))
}
```

Hope that helps :)